# Batch for trying two python versions

Tags: python, batch-file, batch-processing, try-except

The system will have a possible Python version of 2.4.5 or 2.7.9 only. I'm trying to write a batch error handling to try use python 2.7.9 first, and if that fails, use python 2.4.5.

**Conditions**

System has company installed software and will only have Python 2.4.5 or Python 2.7.9. And I won't know which one, so my scripts have to be backwards compatible.

**This is what I have**

```
rem
@echo off

echo Building
"%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\CompanyName\python\python27\python.exe" build.py

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO TRY-PYTHON-24
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO FINISHED-BUILDING

:TRY-PYTHON-24
"%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\CompanyName\python\python24\python.exe" build.py

IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO FINISHED-BUILDING


:FINISHED-BUILDING:
echo Done
...more code...
```

**Expected Result**

Try and use Python 2.7.9 first, if there is `ERRORLEVEL 1`, then try Python 2.4.5. There won't be an error there. Is this the correct way of writing a  batch version of `try` `except` statement like Python?

Such as..

```
try:
    ...Python 2.7.9...
except:
    ...Python 2.4.5...
```

**Sources**

I wrote this based on Microsoft's guide (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/39585). But I'm unsure if this is the best method to a `try` `except` on two versions of Python.

Comment: Probably. It's actually error `9009` but `if errorlevel` means that number or higher. So anything 1 or higher.

Comment: Assuming that the `ERRORLEVEL` approach can work: the first `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` statement is useless, just `GOTO FINISHED-BUILDING` is enough; after the second try (Python 2.4.5), you should place `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO Error. & GOTO :EOF)` or something similar to handle the case when the second try also fails; in your code as is, you would fall into the `:FINISHED-BUILDING` part (remove the trailing `:` there!) even in case of failure;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to the general case of try-except constructs in batch files, but there is a much simpler way to solve this particular problem: use the PATH variable.  The code shown can be replaced with

```
@echo off
set "PATH=%PATH%;%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\WatchGuard\python\python27"
set "PATH=%PATH%;%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\WatchGuard\python\python24"
python build.py || exit /b

rem ... more code ...
```

Setting PATH this way makes the batchfile interpreter automatically look for `python.exe` in both of the directories where it could be.  If *both* versions of Python are installed, it will take the one earlier in the list, i.e. the one in `...\python27`.  (Note that this means if there is *some other* version of Python installed in a directory that already appeared in PATH when the script was invoked, that one will be used.  This is probably what someone who set their system up that way wants.)

Comment: beter use set `"PATH=%PATH%;%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\WatchGuard\python\python24"` otherwise you'll set quotes inside PATH variable which can cause errors.

Comment: @npocmaka I'm not sure I understood your suggested change, did I get it right?

Comment: yes. Path value should not contain quotes  - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060929-06/?p=29533/

Comment: @npocmaka My confusion is not about whether the ultimate value of PATH should end up containing quotes, but about the batch syntax.  To my (much more familiar with sh than batch) brain, `set PATH="whatever"` and `set "PATH=whatever"` should have exactly the same effects, and conceivably `set PATH=whatever` might be more correct than either. But it sounds like you are saying that `set PATH="whatever"` is different from `set "PATH=whatever"`? *Really*?

Comment: it is different. `set path="smth"` will put the quotes in the path value . `set "path=smth"` is considered as a safe way to be sure that nothing redundant will be set in the variable value (like unwanted spaces at the end)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `IF EXIST` :

```
set "p279="%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\WatchGuard\python\python27\python.exe""
set "p245="%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\WatchGuard\python\python24\python.exe""

if exist %p279% (
   set "python=%p279%"
) else (
  set "python=%p245%"
)

call %python% build.py
```